# Add Indexes correctly to a large database table

Tags: mysql, sql

The problem is that after I insert 200.000-300.000 rows of data into those columns the search moves very slow and my first thing that came in mind is the indexes that I may have not added correctly. I have tried adding as many as possible BTREE indexes phpmyadmin did not let me to add for all. What would be the correct indexes for my table? I have the following table with the following indexes:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `carads` (
  `ADID` int(7) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `LINK` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET latin1 NOT NULL,
  `TITLE` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `MAKE` varchar(50) CHARACTER SET latin1 NOT NULL,
  `MODEL` varchar(100) CHARACTER SET latin1 NOT NULL,
  `FUEL` varchar(50) CHARACTER SET latin1 NOT NULL,
  `LOC` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `TRANS` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `YEAR` varchar(4) CHARACTER SET latin1 NOT NULL,
  `BODY` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET latin1 NOT NULL,
  `DESCRIPT` text CHARACTER SET latin1 NOT NULL,
  `PHONENR` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `MILEAGE` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `PRICE` int(20) NOT NULL,
  `DISTANCE` int(250) NOT NULL,
  `POSTCODE` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
  `IMAGE1` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `IMAGE2` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `IMAGE3` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `IMAGE4` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `IMAGE5` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `CPHONE` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
  `CEMAIL` varchar(500) NOT NULL,
  `COLOUR` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
  `EQUIPMENT` text NOT NULL,
  `STATUS` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `DATE` date NOT NULL,
  `DEL` int(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`ADID`),
  KEY `ix_MakeModelPrice` (`STATUS`,`MAKE`(25),`MODEL`(25),`PRICE`),
  KEY `ix_Price` (`PRICE`,`STATUS`,`DEL`,`TITLE`(30),`ADID`),
  KEY `ix_Date` (`DATE`,`STATUS`,`DEL`,`TITLE`(30),`ADID`),
  KEY `LINK` (`LINK`),
  FULLTEXT KEY `MODEL` (`MODEL`),
  FULLTEXT KEY `SearchIndex`  (`TITLE`,`LOC`,`TRANS`,`CPHONE`,`CEMAIL`,`COLOUR`,`EQUIPMENT`),
  FULLTEXT KEY `MAKE` (`MAKE`)
) 
ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=2478687;
```

Comment: Show us the SQL of one or more slow queries. Indexes must be created according to the queries.

Comment: It's like a search box with multiple criteria and max query would be for example `SELECT * FROM carads where STATUS=1 and DEL=0 AND MATCH(MAKE) AGAINST('Alfa Romeo') and BODY = 'Estate' AND MATCH(MODEL) AGAINST('159') and PRICE <= 1000 and PRICE >= 100 and FUEL = 'Electric' and MILEAGE <= 10000 and YEAR>=1999 and TRANS='Manual' AND MATCH(TITLE, LOC, TRANS, CPHONE, CEMAIL, COLOUR, EQUIPMENT) AGAINST('white') AND (LOC='' OR LOC='' OR LOC='') order by ADID Desc LIMIT 0, 10` but even so if I choose only one criteria is still moving hard.

Comment: what time this query takes and which index it use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is very complicated and we cannot give you the correct answer, you have to understand and find the best answer by yourself.

You have to keep following in mind:

1. The query optimizer will choose only one index.
2. Indexes which start with something like "status" and or "del" (boolean values or values where 95% of the rows have the selected values) don't add any value, besides these dummy columns are followed with often queried, highly selective values.

You should first find the attributes which are

- filled in most of the queries (I could imagine that "make", "price" and "year" are good candidates)
- are most selective (meaning that the resulting rows are < 10%)

You have to find out which distribution of values for each of the columns exist in your table. Examples:

Make:

- BMW: 5%
- Alfa Romeo: 1%
- VW: 7%
- ...

Price-Range:

- 0..999: 3%
- 1000..1999: 4%
- 2000..3000: 5%
- ...

If 80% of all searches contain "make", "price" and "year", then create an index with all 3 columns. Put the columns which are most selective and/or are mentioned in most searches to the front, followed by the other columns.

With some luck you can improve response time of many searches dramatically. You can then dig deeper into statistics and add some other indexes. Maybe 80% of all searches have a selection for "make", but in the rest there are still many searches without "make", but with focus on "price" and "fuel", then create an index for those searches.

You could as well improve performance when you use "codes" (e.g. Alfa Romeo=1, BMW=2, VW=3, ...) or cluster ranges of values (e.g. price_range: 0..999, 1000..2000, ...). This could help MySQL to build a bit more efficient indexes (smaller leads to less memory footprint and less I/0).

And to understand indexes better, try to submit a query like this (I want that index `ix_MakeModelPrice` is used):

```sql
-- ix_MakeModelPrice: STATUS`,`MAKE`(25),`MODEL`(25),`PRICE`

SELECT * FROM carads
    where STATUS=1 AND MAKE='Alfa Romeo' 
      AND MODEL='159' and PRICE BETWEEN 100 and 1000
    order by ADID Desc
    LIMIT 0
```

This query should be fast (hopefully with some matching rows). Do you see why it is fast? "STATUS" is not selective, but the rest should reduce the number of rows found with an index-scan to probably way below 1%. The number of physical reads (rows) is reduced to a minimum => faster response.